# laravel 'Undefined index:' when mixing a js file

Tags: laravel, webpack

I am trying to figure out laravel for a small project I am working on.

I want to load a js file on a particular view(not the entire app) so I have created a `client.js` file in `resources/assets/js`

In the view --

`<script src="{{ mix('js/client.js') }}"></script>`

in webpack.mix.js

`mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js', 'resources/assets/js/client.js')`

And run `npm run dev` which doesn't return any errors.

However when I try to load the view in question I get the error --

`Undefined index: /js/client.js (View: /var/www/resources/views/devices/search.blade.php)`

What am I doing wrong/ missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mix.js(from, to)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#working-with-scripts) expects 2 arguments. The file to transform and location where to transform it to. So the `resources/assets/js/client.js` isn't transforming anywhere.

You probably want to do this:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
  .js('resources/assets/js/client.js', 'public/js/client.js)
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it. Strange that it doesn't throw an error when it gets three arguments instead of two.